# How to get article id on BT CONTENT SLIDER?

Tags: module, articles, custom-field, joomla3.8

I have a BT CONTENT SLIDER module on main page of my website to show a list of 3 articles from category called "News" on main page.

I would like to read custom params of that articles shown on that component, on `/templates/mytemplate/html/default.php`. I googled a lot and tested some solutions, but I could not not find a way to get article ids.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the last try, I got the way to get all three articles on BT CONTENT SLIDER:

```
$list = modBtContentSliderHelper::getList( $params, $module );
foreach($list as $article){
  echo $article->id;
}
```

To get the id only from current article, it is so easy:

```
echo $row->id;
```